# Unable to run mksdcard SDK tool" what should i do in this case of installing android studio?

Tags: android-studio

I have tried to install android studio and i have already installed java jdk but my android studio setup says this "Unable to run mksdcard SDK tool".

Answer (score 5):

[Apparently](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82711) you need to install few 32-bit binaries because the build-tools are not shipped with only 32-binaries. So if you are using a 64-bit OS the following should make it work:

> `sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6`

Comment: did not work with my frsh ubuntu 16 isntall. any idea what to do on ubuntu 16?