# Unable to run mksdcard SDK tool ubuntu 16, 2016

Tags: software-installation, permissions, android

Followed [How to install Android Studio on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/634082/how-to-install-android-studio-on-ubuntu) to install android studio. But get error (hardware :  aspire e15 E5-573G):

> Downloading android-sdk_r22.6.2-linux.tgz from
>   https://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r22.6.2-linux.tgz Unpacking
>   android-sdk_r22.6.2-linux.tgz tar xzvfC
>   /tmp/AndroidStudio0FirstRun/android-sdk_r22.6.2-linux.tgz
>   /tmp/AndroidStudio0FirstRun/android-sdk_r22.6.2-linux.tgz-unpacked
>
> Unable to run mksdcard SDK tool.

Its a new ubuntu install. just used firefox and the text editor. have used ubuntu before (a year ago) but first time with android studio. i had to launch android with sudo command in /opt folder

then moved to ~/apps (a new folder in home folder, did a :

> sudo chmod 777 *
>   sudo chmod -R 777 *

But still same error.

- Then found [Unable to run mksdcard SDK tool" what should i do in this case of installing android studio?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/634609/unable-to-run-mksdcard-sdk-tool-what-should-i-do-in-this-case-of-installing-and) but those packages dont instlal either

> sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From other answers found and ran

A. steps at : https://askubuntu.com/a/253946/165511

1. Kill the process named apt-get:

   ```
   killall -9 apt-get
   ```

   2. Reconfigure dpkg:

   ```
   dpkg --configure -a
   ```

   3. Update apt-get:

   ```
   apt-get update
   ```

   4. Update packages, including those improperly installed:

   ```
   apt-get upgrade
   ```

B. Was able to run :

sudo apt-get install  lib32stdc++6

C. When that did not work realized it was a permissoins issue too:
had moved the folder from /opt to ~ but had not changed owner.

chmod -R  android-studio

Then ran the studio again ./android-studio/bin/studio.sh